# Alert message when Woocommerce shipping method 'local pickup' selected at checkout

Tags: jquery, woocommerce

I'm trying to pop up an alert when the customer selects "local pickup" as the shipping method to confirm that's what they really intended. This is the code I tried but it's not working:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    var localPickupMsg = 'alert message text will go here';
    jQuery('input:radio[name="shipping_method"]').change(function() {
        if (jQuery(this).val() == 'local_pickup'){
            alert(localPickupMsg);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: If my answer doesn't help please provide any console error messages

Comment: It is not going to work, as woocommerce is restricting the default click action.

Answer (score 0):

The `:radio` selector is deprecated.

use

```
input[type=radio][name=shipping_method]
```

Comment: Thanks, but it's still not working. I'm not seeing any errors in the debug.log.